# Какую связь нужно организовать между таблицами?

Tags: sql

Имеется две таблицы: `Мастер` и `Заказ`. Какая связь здесь нужна?
Я думаю так: связать эти таблицы по специальности, т.е. мастер со своей уникальной специальностью может иметь множество заказов, но определенный заказ может выполнить только один мастер. Догадываюсь, что это связь один-ко-многим, но как это организовать - не знаю.

Вот таблицы:

```
--------------------------------------------
create table [master]
(
    Фамилия varchar(100) not null primary key,
    Имя varchar(100) not null,
    Отчество varchar(100) not,
    Специализация varchar(100) not null
)
--------------------------------------------------------------
create table [order]
(
    Дата date not null,
    Уникальный_код varchar(100) not null primary key,
    Модель varchar(100) foreign key references client(Модель),
    Номер_детали int not null,
    Нужная_специализация varchar(100)
)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Если что - это вырезка из БД.

Comment: Раз на заказе только один мастер, то в таблицу order добавляем поле master_id которое ссылается на id мастера из masters (да, id туда стоит добавить, не надо делать фамилию или еще что то первичным ключем). А то у вас сейчас не может быть двух мастеров Иванов. И мастер фамилию может поменять, как потом ссылки править все будете ...

Comment: Спасибо) Так и сделаю)

Answer (score 2):

Тут выборка **INNER JOIN**.То eсть выберет все совпадения, а которые не совпали проигнорирует.Если вам надо выбрать всех мастеров то вместо **INNER JOIN** напишите **LEFT OUTER JOIN**.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

```
CREATE TABLE `masters`
(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pkId PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE `orders`
(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `master_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `price` FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT pkId PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (master_id) REFERENCES masters(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

SELECT
    `m`.`id` AS `mastr_id`,
    `m`.`name` AS `master_name`,
    `o`.`id` AS `order_id`,
    `o`.`price` AS `price`
FROM
    `masters` `m`
INNER JOIN `orders` `o`
ON `m`.`id` = `o`.`master_id`
```

Comment: on delete cascade довольно опасная опция. не стоит ее в примерах предлагать. так же можно случайно половину всех заказов потерять удалив одного мастера. Да и вопрос касается структуры БД, а не видов join в запросе

Comment: Спасибо за таблицу) Выборка не нужна была.

Comment: @Mike Если не упоминать то не знающий человек может и не узнать ,и навредить себе вдвойне.Можно всегда найти ответ на интересующие вопросы.Тем более я прикрепил ссылку где поподробней объясняют

Comment: @PoGostu Всегда пожалуйста.Если вы считаете ответ исчерпывающим то поставьте галочку возле ответа,чтобы другие легко могли cориентироваться на правильный ответ.Спасибо

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Вот именно, что незнающий человек может эти on delete casade просто скопировать. А в 99% случаев автоудаление заказов при удалении мастера вредно. Лучше пусть орет, что мастера удалить нельзя.

Comment: @Mike Тут можно долго спорить по этому вопросу .Лично я так не считаю.Можно какую нибудь таблицу для этого держать, например отчет (report).А потом с ней делай всё что хочешь.На мой взгляд он более оптимален.А если он завтра захочет таблицу транзакций.Получится что и там данные будут копиться.А если еще чего то.Так что однозначно тоже нельзя сказать.Хотя ваши доводы тоже уместны.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table [master]
(
  id_Мастера int not null primary key,
  Фамилия varchar(100) not null,
  Имя varchar(100) not null,
  Отчество varchar(100) not,
  Специализация varchar(100) not null
)

create table [order]
(
  Дата date not null primary key,
  Уникальный_код varchar(100) not,
  Модель varchar(100) not null foreign key references client(Модель),
  Номер_детали int not null foreign key references detail(Номер),
  id_Мастера int not null foreign key references master(id_Мастера)

)
```

Я думаю это окончательное решение.